# hide side panel in webview21 using c#

Tags: c#, winforms, asp.net-core, webforms, webview2

I displayed localhost webpage in winform using webview2.Now my requirement is I want hide the side panel  in winform webview2 but the panenl should be visible in webform. I tried below codes to achieve this but it is not happening

webView21.CoreWebView2.ExecuteScriptAsync("document.getElementById('myDiv').style.visibility = 'hidden';");

webView21.CoreWebView2.ExecuteScriptAsync("document.getElementById('myDiv').style.display = 'none';");

webView21.CoreWebView2.ExecuteScriptAsync("document.getElementsById('myDiv')[0].style.visibility = 'hidden';");

webView21.CoreWebView2.ExecuteScriptAsync("document.getElementsById('myDiv')[0].style.display = 'none';");

webView21.CoreWebView2.ExecuteScriptAsync(""+"document.getElementsById('myDiv')[0].style.visibility = 'hidden';");

webView21.CoreWebView2.ExecuteScriptAsync(""+"document.getElementsById('myDiv')[0].style.display = 'none';");

I applied above mentioned codes but none of these are working

Comment: `await webView21.ExecuteScriptAsync("document.getElementById('myDiv').style.display = 'none';");` -- Note the `await` operator. Also, the element is supposed to be part of the main Document (not the Document of an IFrame)

Comment: @Jimi I tried 
await webView21.ExecuteScriptAsync("document.getElementById('myDiv').style.display = 'none';");
still not happening

Comment: Then the ID is wrong, the element has no ID at all or the element is not part of the current Document. See whether the HTML contains IFrames. -- You also need to specify when / where you're using that code. -- Anyway, try also `document.querySelector("#myDiv")`

Comment: Press 'F12' and check if you have an element called 'myDiv'.

Comment: Make sure you are calling ExecuteScriptAsync after the page has finished parsing so that your myDiv element exists. If you run ExecuteScriptAsync too early the page will not have finished parsing yet and your myDiv element won't exist yet. You may be able to use the CoreWebView2.DOMContentLoaded event to find out when the DOM has first been parsed.